Make Snake move smoother, look like Google Snake in unity
Trying to make a snake game, but my version is a little complex, because I am not using a single green or black box for snake, I use different sprites for snake head, tail, body, and corner like this. My final target is to do something like the Google Snake game.
I've already done most of the mechanism of a snake game: move, grow, the corners caused by change move direction. The movements of the snake are based on a abstract two-dimensional grid map. I treated the snake as consisting of a list of snake node, one snake could be like this:
head <- body <- corner <- ... <- tail.
These nodes inherit relationship is :
class BaseNode; // BaseNode just handles the four direcion sprites
class SnakeNode: BaseNode;
class SnakeCorner: SnakeNode;
class SnakeHead: SnakeNode; // Singleton
class SnakeTail: SnakeNode; // Singleton

public class SnakeNode : BaseNode
{
    public SnakeNode prev;
    public SnakeNode next;
    public Vector2Int gridPos; // The pos in the abstract two-dimensional grid map.
    // every snake node have its direction
    protected Vector2Int _direction;

    // SnakeCorner will override this property
    public virtual Vector2Int Direction
    {
        get => _direction;
        set
        {
         // ...
         // some code auto set spriterender.sprite when change the direction
        }
    }
}

I defined one function to map the grid pos to world pos, here is what I do.
public Vector2 Grid2WorldPosition(int row, int col)
{
    var offset = new Vector2(setting.cols, setting.rows) / 2;

    return (new Vector2(col ,row) - offset) * setting.scale;
}

And how I move the snake:
private BaseNode[,] gridMap;

private void MoveSnack() {
    var tail = SnackTail.Instance;
    var newTailPos = tail.prev.gridPos;
    var newTailDir = tail.prev.Direction;

    var head = SnackHead.Instance;
    var oldPos = head.gridPos;
    var newPos = head.gridPos + new Vector2Int(head.Direction.y, head.Direction.x);
    if (CheckOutOfBounds(newPos.x, newPos.y)) {
        // some code limit bounds
    }

    if (gridMap[newPos.x, newPos.y] != null) {
        // some code handle eat apple or collision.
    }

    GameObject gameObj;
    if (head.Direction != head.next.Direction)
    {
        // some code create SnakeCorner obj
    }
    else
    {
        // some code create common SnakeNode obj
    }
    var body = gameObj.GetComponent<SnackNode>();
    body.Direction = head.Direction;
    body.gridPos = oldPos;

    SnackListHandler.Insert(head, body);

    head.gridPos = newPos;

    // here is what I do to update postion on the abstract map.
    gridMap[newPos.x, newPos.y] = head;
    gridMap[oldPos.x, oldPos.y] = body;
    gridMap[tail.gridPos.x, tail.gridPos.y] = null;
    gridMap[newTailPos.x, newTailPos.y] = tail; 

    tail.Direction = newTailDir;
    tail.gridPos = newTailPos;

    // just update head and tail positon is enough
    var nodes = new SnackNode[]{head, tail};
    foreach (var node in nodes) {
        node.transform.position = Grid2WorldPosition(node.gridPos.x, node.gridPos.y);
    }

    if (tail.prev != head)
        SnackListHandler.Remove(tail.prev);
}

SnackListHandler handles the Snake Nodes prev, next relationship as linked-list, I think there is no need put its code here, perhaps...
The problem is that when I run over the MoveSnack function, the head and tail postion is like "Jump" to its new world pos, causing feeling stuck. And I have tried the lerp way, but it does not act as I like, perhaps lerp is able to let my snake move like that Google Snake, but I don't know how to.
Welcome for any advice, ideas, to recreatw the Google Snake Game.
Snake Move

Why don't you just use a TrailRenderer ..?

@derHugo TrailRenderer do something like arrow trail is good, but is it good enough to represent the whole snake? There have some collision work need to do, and animations

It works as designed, nothing more. You move your snake using the discrete grid, and the parts change positions based on that.
What can you do to make it smoother:

split logic position and view position
leave logic as it works right now in your code (with discrete grid)
implement the view movement logic that will move your snake part to the target (logically current) position using Lerp.
Ensure you only allow input to be applied on "reaching logical points," i.e., your logical tick.
Consider that your view movement depends on view updates, so you must also anticipate the situation when your snake changes direction in the middle of your update.


Thank you for your answer first. Snake change direction, that's the point.  In my implemention of snake there have some masking problem in change direction if you don't "Jump" to next grid position. Could you tell more about your ideal about handle the "Change Direction" situation?


calculate the distance that needs to be passed based on dt. 2. calculate the new visual position based on the condition "if the direction was changed." If yes - calculate the result position with the consideration of changing direction.


As mentioned in the comments I would use a different approach. You want to separate the visuals from the logic/functionality

Like Morion describes first of all you need to ensure a smooth grid based movement using Lerp
phrased a bit different though: You do not want to only take input on the tick based but rather store the last pressed direction until the tick is reached and then process the new direction.
As code this might look somewhat like
[SerializeField] float moveDuration = 1f; // seconds it takes to move one grid unit (for now == unity unit)

// maps keycodes to according move directions
private static readonly Dictionary<KeyCode, Vector2> directions = new Dictionary<MoveDirection, Vector2>()
{
    { KeyCode.UpArrow, Vector2.up },
    { KeyCode.DownArrow, Vector2.down },
    { KeyCode.LeftArrow, Vector2.left },
    { KeyCode.RightArrow, Vector2.right }
};

// not allowed to handle input that inverts the direction
private static readonly Dictionary<MoveDirection, MoveDirection> forbiddenDirections = new Dictionary<MoveDirection, MoveDirection>()
{
    { KeyCode.UpArrow, KeyCode.DownArrown},
    { KeyCode.DownArrow, KeyCode.UpArrow},
    { KeyCode.LeftArrow, KeyCode.RightArrow},
    { KeyCode.RightArrow, KeyCode.LeftArrow}
};

// nullable so you can wait for first input
private KeyCode? currentInput;

private IEnumerator Start()
{
    // wait for first key press
    do
    {
        HandleInput();
        yield return null;
    }
    while(currentInput == null);

    // later on replace maybe by condition for death instead
    while(true) 
    {
        // repeatdely check for Input but only process it once per grid movement
        HandleInput();

        // initialize grid movement
        var direction = directions[currentInput];
        var currentPosition = transform.position;
        var targetPosition = currentPosition + direction;

        // TODO: at this point you can already check for food, wall or self collision and trigger an animation
        // and according other reactions

        // use lerp for smooth move one grid unit over moveDuration
        for(var timePassed = 0f; timePassed < moveDuration; timePassed += Time.deltaTime)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(currentPosition, targetPosition, timePassed / moveDuration);
            yield return null;

            // during move keep checking for input but don't apply it until this move finished
            HandleInput();
        }
        // to end with a clean grid position every time
        transform.position = targetPosition;
    }
}

private void HandleInput()
{
    foreach(var keyCode in directions.Keys)
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(keyCode)
        {
            if(currentInput == null || keyCode  != forbiddenDirections[currentInput])
            {
                currentInput = keyCode;
            } 
            break;
        }
    }
}


Then the only thing you actually need to move is the head!
Because: For the entire tail I would use a TrailRenderer. You set it up according to your needs and then simply increase the time (lifetime of the trail points) every time your snake eats accordingly => trail grows longer.

For any additional animations like the bubble after eating you just use a separate object on top of the trail (it actually just needs to stay in position of where you ate while the snake moves over it). Alternatively you could of course also adjust the widthCurve but then you need to update it every frame to let a thicker bubble wander along the trail.

Finally for handling collision of the head with the rest of the body (trail), food amd walls you could

use a PolygonCollider2D. The TrailRenderer provides the positions of current points via GetPositions you can then use to calculate the outline shape.

Or actually even simpler you could also just leave a simple BoxCollider or CircleCollider on each grid you passed that auto-destroys after the same lifetime of the trail renderer points.

Or thinking about it further you wouldn't require collisions at all. You could go fully grid based and in the code above where I commented you could check for any collisions with walls, food, yourself (simply store the last n positions and check if the next target position is already contained in that list. The grid is limited enough to perform good and this would remove any involvement of expensive physics. All you need for this is to store the wall positions, the current food position and the positions you previously walked on. Then simply check if the new target position matches any of these. That's a very limited amount of checks.





Thank you for your analyze.. Use TrailRenderer sounds like great and catch input is not a big problem for now... Honestly, I am not very familiar with TrailRenderer. Like what I discussed with Morion. Handle snake change direction is tricky, because I want to use sprites to represent the corner, can trailrenderer use sprites as trail? I am not sure, later I will check it out and come back.

My question is why sprites? The trail can use any material including ones with textures etc .. there is no need for any sprites imho .. you just configure the trail renderer according to your needs form thickness and round corners etc

well, no sprites. that could be a way save me from the hell of sprite, I am going to use trailrenderer to do something cool
